# Draw a connection line between two elements in pure XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm very very new to WPF and XAML.
I've two `Image` elements placed on a 4x4 `Grid` (say `x:Name='LHImage'` `x:Name='RHImage`) and and I would like to connect them with a line.

Something like this:

```
<Line
    X1="{Binding ElementName=LHImage, Path=RenderedBoundingRect.Right}"
    Y1="{Binding ElementName=LHImage, Path=RenderedBoundingRect.Middle}"
    X2="{Binding ElementName=RHImage, Path=RenderedBoundingRect.Left}"
    Y2="{Binding ElementName=RHImage, Path=RenderedBoundingRect.Middle}"
    Stroke="Gray"
    StrokeThickness="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="4"/>
```

Of course `RenderedBoundingRect` and its `Left` `Right` `Middle` properties don't exist and should be replaced by some other expression that it's just what I'm looking for.
Is that possible in pure XAML (no C# side code)?

**EDIT:**
As requested here is a screenshot of the desired result:

[image]

Comment: can you share your desired output with some visual? something like image.

Answer (score 0):

If you put all your controls in the same container (like a `Canvas`) you could do it with some tricks:

```
<Canvas>
    <Rectangle Height="30" Width="50" Fill="Red">
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <!--Bound transform or absolute transform-->
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="LHImage" X="80" Y="50"/>
                <!--Relative transform-->
                <TranslateTransform X="-50" Y="-15"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    </Rectangle>
    <Rectangle Height="30" Width="50" Fill="Red">
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="RHImage" X="130" Y="20"/>
                <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="-15"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    </Rectangle>
    <Line
        X1="{Binding ElementName=LHImage, Path=X}"
        Y1="{Binding ElementName=LHImage, Path=Y}"
        X2="{Binding ElementName=RHImage, Path=X}"
        Y2="{Binding ElementName=RHImage, Path=Y}"
        Stroke="Gray"
    StrokeThickness="5"/>
</Canvas>
```

But if you use a `Grid` and put your controls in different cells, then you would have to sum some dimensions which is impossible without a simple `Converter`.
So, I would say it's nearly impossible to do without code behind, but the required code can be very short and clear.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sticking to `Grid` method, can you give me a sample using a `Converter`?